# AppleScript to reply to reply-to address

Tags: applescript

I have an AppleScript which replies to a ceratin mail with a specific text.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set myReply to "My Text"

    tell application "Mail"
        set theSelection to selection
        if theSelection is {} then return
        activate
        repeat with thisMessage in theSelection
            set theOutgoingMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window
            repeat until exists (window 1 whose name = "Re: " & subject of thisMessage)
            end repeat
            delay 0.3

            tell application "System Events"
                keystroke myReply
            end tell

            delay 0.5
            send theOutgoingMessage
        end repeat
    end tell

    return input
end run
```

The problem is it always replies to the senders address and not to the reply-to address.

Where can I set the address to the reply-to address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the reply message used, by default, the reply-to address. May be you have special emails....?  Anyways, to force the use of reply-to, you need to read it from thisMessage before the reply, and then assigned it.

You do not need to test if selection is {}: if it is empty, the repeat loop will not start.

Also, instead of using keystroke (always dangerous), I suggest to just set the content of the reply email to your text value directly.

See script bellow with the changes suggested (tested and OK) :

```
set myReply to "My Text"

tell application "Mail"
activate
set theSelection to selection
repeat with thisMessage in theSelection
    set ReplyAddress to reply to of thisMessage
    set theOutgoingMessage to reply thisMessage with opening window
    repeat until name of front window is (subject of theOutgoingMessage)
        delay 0.3
    end repeat

    set content of theOutgoingMessage to (myReply) as rich text
    set A to to recipient 1 of theOutgoingMessage
        set address of to recipient 1 of theOutgoingMessage to ReplyAddress
end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Works perfectly! just added `send theOutgoingMessage` before `end repeat` to trigger the send